# Horizontal center an element thats inside an absolute div?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div - this has to be absolute positioned.

Inside a have a list - this needs to be positioned at the bottom and aligned center. I am having issues with aligning it center.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5ob2ym5/)

I need a solution that will work with IE9 so no flex box. Both the container and ul must stay absolutely positioned.

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>


.container{  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: grey;
position: absolute;
}

ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
li{
display: block;
width: 10%;
float: left;
padding: 0;

}
img{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure why you are doing what you are doing currently, but anyways everyone has a requirement and some do it in an odd way, so here's a fix for your solution

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 1px solid #f00;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/t5ob2ym5/1/)

So here what am doing is, I removed `float` from `li` and assigned `display: inline-block;` so that I can align them to the center in `ul`.

Also note that I've used `font-size: 0;` on `ul` element so that you don't get the white space issue while using `inline-block` for your `li` elements. So if you any day plan to nest text in `li` then define some font size explicitly for the `li` elements.

A tip, never use `float: left;` and `display: block;` together, if you `float: left;` then `display: block;` isn't required anymore.

Comment: @panthro Take a look at `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: bottom;` properties, if you are not a fan of `position: absolute;` so you can use them as well